# Simplify Similar Selectors in Sass

Tags: css, sass

I have the following similar selectors and am trying to refactor them in Sass. What's the most efficient way to do this?

```
.test table td em.green,
.test table td em.red,
.test table td strong.green,
.test table td strong.red,
.report table td em.green,
.report table td em.red,
.report table td strong.green,
.report table td strong.red {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
.test, .report {
    td {
        em, strong {
            &.red, &.green {
                color: red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you only need `table` or `td`, not both (since td's must be descendants of tables, and content within a table must be within either td, th, or caption tags).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`@extend`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend) or using [`@mixin`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins):

for example with [`@extend`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend) you can extend the properties of the other classes and only override what you need to. like so:

```
.error {
  border: 1px #f00;
  background-color: #fdd;
}
.error.intrusion {
  background-image: url("/image/hacked.png");
}
.seriousError {
  @extend .error;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

Using a [`@mixin`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins) will allow you to create a blueprint for easily creating another instance of a class. for example:

```
@mixin sexy-border($color, $width) {
  border: {
    color: $color;
    width: $width;
    style: dashed;
  }
}

p { @include sexy-border(blue, 1in); }
```